# Apache HttpClient use own SSL-certificates

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to connect to a https secured restwebservice using httpclient 4.0.3 with Java7.
My code looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ClientRequest req = new ClientRequest("https://127.0.0.16:8443/rest/lstgs/create", new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(doSSLBlackMagic()));

    // ... random stuff that has nothing to do with SSL

    ClientResponse<String> response = req.post(String.class);
    if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("error, status: " + response.getStatus() + " / " + response.getEntity());
    } else {
        System.out.println(response.getEntity());
    }
}

public static KeyStore loadTrustStore() throws Exception {
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("path-to-truststore")), "password".toCharArray());
    return trustStore;
}

protected static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers() throws Exception {
    KeyStore trustStore = loadTrustStore();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(trustStore);
    return tmf.getTrustManagers();
}

public static HttpClient doSSLBlackMagic() throws Exception {
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = getTrustManagers();
    ctx.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager manager = client.getConnectionManager();
    manager.getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", factory, 8443));

    return client;
}
```

As far as I understand this should result in the HttpClient to use my Truststore to ensure that the server's certificate is valid. This fails. I keep getting this exception:

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

I've tried multiple keystore/truststores or a plain URLConnection Java-Solution. Nothing works. Is there any way to validate a given keystore and truststore with each other? Is there some other way to set the truststore? How can I debug this?

EDIT:
Full Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:399)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.execute(ApacheHttpClient4Executor.java:87)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:39)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.execute(AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.java:40)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:45)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.execute(ClientRequest.java:473)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.httpMethod(ClientRequest.java:704)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.post(ClientRequest.java:595)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.post(ClientRequest.java:600)
at TestLstgCreation.main(TestLstgCreation.java:49)
```

EDIT2:
I've tried this piece of pure Code without HttpClient:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            System.err.println("foobar");
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            System.err.println("foobar");
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            System.err.println("foobar");
        }
    } };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            System.err.println("foobar");
            return true;
        }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);

    URL url = new URL("https://127.0.0.16:8443/rest/lstgs/ofclient/23891");

    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.connect();
}
```

It fails and does not print foobar at all:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1837)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1019)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1230)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1214)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
at ScrewYouApacheHttpClient.main(ScrewYouApacheHttpClient.java:48)
```

The certifciate that the server is using was only "valid" until 2010, maybe that is a problem? Yesterday I did try to use another certificate that I created for this test and got the same results, though.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the solution:
We just recently switched to Java 7 and the Eclipseprojekt I used for this test still used Java 6. The Server I am working against however already uses Java 7. Running the Code above with Java 7 works for both snippets. :)

Sucks that the Exception gives no information about this, it cost me a few hours of my life :/

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your `TrustManager` is validating the certificate, but HTTPS hostname verification is failing.  Consider adding

```
factory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```