# Key stores from Websphere

Tags: java, websphere

How can I get key stores from IBM Websphere in Spring that is located in Websphere?

```
Security > SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates
```

Is it possible to create the bean and use it, or use it as something different?

Can I use it through the JNDI?

Comment: What is it that you want ot do with the keystores? Add keys to them? You could add a custom trust manager to authenticate against your own certificates.

Comment: no, I want to get trust store from websphre to use in jetty httpclient, because i need to trust store to connect with one application.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy or supported way to get to the store programmatically. Why don't you export the certificates you need from the WAS store, create a new store and import the certificates into it. Then add this new cert-store to your sources and use it in jetty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the code in this question for accessing a KeyStore programmatically and using it from httpclient

[Apache HttpClient use own SSL-certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698462/apache-httpclient-use-own-ssl-certificates)